# differences between ms sql microsoft's jdbc drivers and jTDS's driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

What are the differences between each driver? I mean, besides one of them being open-source

What are the pros / cons of each one?

Which one would you recommend?

---

here's jTDS own opinion on the subject: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I can't imagine choosing a Microsoft Java integration component over something like jTDS.

Comment: Atlassian's documentation for Confluence recommends using JTDS over the MS JDBC jar when connecting to SQL Server...

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186932/using-jtds-driver

Comment: Thanks for the link, Stephen, I really did a search on SO but I seem to have missed that question...

Comment: "besides one of them being open-source" - Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server is now [open-source](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) and is under active development.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are distinct implementations.  The jTDS driver is a type 4 and in my experience has better performance.  I have been using the jTDS driver in a production environment without any issues for 5 years.

I would recommend going with jTDS.

Comment: The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver is a type 4 driver as well. And while it has improved over the last few years, it still isn't as good and stable as jTDS.

Comment: Whereas support for XA always involves a native SQL server side component

Comment: The [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver is now open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) as well.

Comment: Please consider that the JTDS driver has not been updated since 2013 and only supports JDBC 3.0.The Microsoft driver implements JDBC 4.3 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017#70) and exists in a Java 11 version.

Answer (score 16):

While for many years jTDS was much superior than buggy mssql's own driver, the things are changing to the opposite recently.

Here is qoute from https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/transitioning-from-jtds-to-microsoft-s-jdbc-driver-776640388.html:

> **Why change drivers?**
>
> Recent releases of Hibernate, which Bitbucket Server uses to simplify
>   its persistence layer, have introduced a requirement that the JDBC
>   drivers and connection pools used be JDBC4-compliant. JDBC4 was
>   introduced with Java 6.
>
> The jTDS driver used by releases prior to Bitbucket Server 2.1 is a
>   JDBC3 driver, compatible with Java 1.3, and therefore cannot be used
>   with newer versions of Hibernate. While jTDS 1.3.0 and 1.3.1 claim to
>   implement JDBC4, and JDBC4.1, they actually don't. The new methods
>   have been "implemented", but their implementations are all throw new
>   AbstractMethodError(), which means they can't actually be used. (See
>   an example [here, on GitHub](https://github.com/milesibastos/jTDS/blob/master/src/main/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsPreparedStatement.java#L1261-L1265).)
>
> Since jTDS 1.3.1 does not provide a functioning JDBC4 implementation,
>   the decision was made to replace jTDS with Microsoft's own SQL Server
>   driver. Microsoft's driver is actively maintained, where jTDS hasn't
>   been updated since 2014 (and prior to the small round of updates done
>   in 2014 it hadn't been updated for multiple years). Microsoft offers a
>   full JDBC4.2 (Java 8) driver and supports all the features of SQL
>   Server, including SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Yes, jTDS is considerably out of date. Last year I upgraded an app to java 8 and found there is a bug when using jTDS in java 8 with SSL. Depspite there having been a bug report with working patch in the jTDS sourceforge forum since 2014, the driver still hasn't been updated to fix it. I had to build my own copy to include the fix. Now this week I'm discovering another bug. When querying a datetime2 column, getMetaData is reporting the column type incorrectly as nvarchar. The microsoft driver works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

One relevant difference is, that the JDBC 4.0 Implementation of the JTDS-Driver (v1.3.1) requires at least Java 7, whereas the JDBC 4.0 Implementation of the Microsoft driver is available in Java 6.

This is important if you want to use Hibernate 4.3 (relying on JDBC 4.0 API) and support Java 6. In that case JTDS is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

The key reason FOR using jTDS is that it uses the lesser GPL license where Microsoft's driver uses their own license which has much more restrictions to it. One restriction of note is that you may not

> - work around any technical limitations in the software

There are more restrictions within the license such as:

> - transfer the software or this agreement to any third party
> - use the software for commercial software hosting services

Which could be interpreted that you may not use it in production code, however earlier points in the license seem to allow it.

Having said all of this, I don't know of the licenses within SQL Server itself which may or may not restrict third-party drivers such as jTDS connecting to it.

Another point is that jTDS is available via maven, the Microsoft driver is not.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For my choice, use jTDS, it is more permissive and least likely to get you into trouble, and; it's a better driver.

Comment: Since November 2016, the Microsoft driver is available on Github under the MIT License : https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc, and on Maven Central under groupId "com.microsoft.sqlserver"

Answer (score 2):

jTDSperformance is good, but looks like the fail-over property is not supported by jTDS, if the SQL Server switches to secondary, needed to restart the application/server for picking the new ip and reseting the connection.

Answer (score 0):

jTDS 1.3.1 (the latest released version) has problem with the TLS, what can be a game-changer for some people. The problems might have started with Java 8 - I saw such comment - but it's not verified. There's a "private", not released fix - see e.g. https://community.microfocus.com/cyberres/idm/w/identity_mgr_tips/19661/enforcing-ssl-tlsv1-2-jdbc-connection-via-jtds-jdbc-driver
It worked for me.
Below you can find an exception generated while trying to connect to the MS SQL using the original jTDS 1.3.1 and TLS:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection reset
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at jtds.JtdsMain.getData(JtdsMain.java:30)
    at jtds.JtdsMain.start(JtdsMain.java:15)
    at jtds.JtdsMain.main(JtdsMain.java:9)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.TdsTlsInputStream.readFully(TdsTlsInputStream.java:131)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.TdsTlsInputStream.primeBuffer(TdsTlsInputStream.java:100)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.TdsTlsInputStream.read(TdsTlsInputStream.java:78)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.SocketFactories$TdsTlsSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactories.java:101)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.enableEncryption(SharedSocket.java:330)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.negotiateSSL(TdsCore.java:577)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:365)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).